# What's the difference between A a; and A a();?

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization, most-vexing-parse

What is the difference between the declarations of the classes below?

```
class A
{
public:
    A()
    {
        std::cout << "A()\n";
    }
    ~A()
    {
        std::cout << "~A()\n";
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    A a; // <-- this call the constructor and destructor
    A b(); // <-- this is not!! what is a b()?
    return 0;
}
```

What is a `b()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) issue; a side effect of C++’s rule that anything that can be parsed as a
declaration must be interpreted as one. So `A b();` is a function declaration, `b` is a function takes nothing and returns `A`.

From C++11, you can use braces ([list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization)) instead of parentheses; because functions can’t be declared using braces for the parameter list, the "ambiguity" goes away.

```
A b{}; // calls A's default constructor
```

Comment: Please lets not answer obvious dupes